# calculate big oh notation with for loop condition

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analysis

I am trying to understand the calculation of Big-oh notation of a function, when a function contains a for-loop, which has a specific ***condition***

> for (initialization, **condition**, increment)

or() like below:

```c
    public void functE( int n ) 
    {
       int a;
       for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
           for ( int j = 0; j <= n - i; j++ )
               a = i;
    }
```

I suppose the big-oh of this function to be **O(n^2)**, is this valid?

Comment: How did you arrive at O(n2)?

Comment: Given that the code is side-effect free and returns `void`, the runtime should be `O(0)`.

Comment: @EOF: I think the assumption is you *aren't* using an optimizing compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a = i` takes 1 time unit, you can consider each `i`:

- i = 0 : n + 1
- i = 1 : n
- i = 2 : n - 1
- ...
- i = n - 1 : 2

So in total:

T(n) = (n+1) + (n) + (n-1) + ... + 2 = n + [1 + ... + n] = n + n * (n + 1)/2 = (n^2 + 3n) / 2 = O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

by using tabular method ,complexity is n^2+(2-i)n+2

a cording to the Big-Oh notation,

```
let f(n)=n^2+(2-i)n+2
f(n) <= c*g(n)
n^2+(2-i)n+2 <= n^2+(2-i)n+(2-i)n
n^2+(2-i)n+2 <= n^2+2(2-i)n
n^2+(2-i)n+2 <= n^2+n^2
n^2+(2-i)n+2 <= 2n^2
```

therefore, c=2 and g(n)=n^2,
**f(n)=O(g(n)) = O(n^2)**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You seem to know what you're doing, but I'm afraid I can't follow you. Would you mind to elaborate? More to the point: I'm familiar with the Landau O, but I don't know the tabular method. Can you provide us a link? And I don't see the connection between your formulas and the source code of the question. I'd appreciate explanations of each line. Thanks in advance!